# Multiple data points in a graph's labels

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to build a bar graph in excel. The thing i'm having issues with is the formatting of the labels on the datapoints. I'd like the labels to pull from 2 datasets. The bar would be drawn using the first data point say "66%" but i'd like the label to show the percent and the count, something like "66% (14)"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to calculate the label as 1 column, e.g.

```
=TEXT([@Percent], "0%") & " (" & [@Value] & ")"
```

Then if you don't need to preserve the category, just choose this column as the Axis Label (you can also add category in the above formula).

But if you want to separate the axis category from the labels, you will need to do following (steps based on Excel 2010):

1. insert a **Stacked Bar** chart, based only on `Category` and `Percent` columns
2. add `Data Labels` > `Inside Base` for the whole chart
3. add a 2nd series based on the `Label` column (via right-click `Select Data...` > `Add`, do not change Axis Labels at this stage) - all values will be 0 because it is a text column
4. delete the original Percent-only labels
5. right-click on the 0 labels and choose `Format Data Series...` > Plot Series on `Secondary Axis`
6. delete the secondary axis itself that appeared on top of chart
7. right-click on 0 labels again, `Format Data Labels...` > tick `Category Name` and untick `Value`
8. in `Select Data...` dialog, choose the `Label` series and click `Edit` Axis Labels (right column) - choose the `Label` column for the labels

Note you can also choose the `Percent` column as the values of your `Label` series combined with the `Inside End` data labels option for the labels to appear at the right-hand side of the bars, but you will need to make sure that both primary and secondary axes are scaled the same.

[image: dual_label_printscreen]

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2013 provides an option which allow to adding separate values from cells > see button `Select Range...`

[image: Example]