# 2 labels for one series in the chart bar

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I would like to have 2 labels per series used in my bar chart in Excel.
[image]

As you see below, I've managed with the labels and their placement & rotation, however, I would like to have them 2 per series located for both sides. How can I do it in Excel 2016?

I found some thread here:

https://www.excelforum.com/excel-charting-and-pivots/811351-multiple-data-labels-on-bar-chart.html

where they propose to duplicate the series and make one of them transparent. It doesn't convince me I am afraid because I am going to have up to 50-60 series.

Is there some method, which would allow me to simply add another label to the given series? When I select more than 1 series option, they appear after comma only. In fact, I can change their separation, but they will still act on the same side.

Comment: [Check this help you,,,](https://superuser.com/questions/864937/multiple-data-points-in-a-graphs-labels)

Comment: @RajeshSinha it doesn't help me, as I can get just another label in the separate line. It could if the space between the type of values would be custom.